# git simple merge does not merge

Tags: git, merge

File `conf.yaml` on master:

```
food=steak
drink=water
```

File `conf.yaml` on dev:

```
food=steak
```

While on `dev` branch i run:

```
$ git merge master
Already up to date.
```

To merge from master obviously, but:

`cat conf.yaml` (from dev), shows:
`food=steak`
The merge is not successful, shal i use some extra option together with the merge command?
I cant find this info on https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Comment: Double-check that `master` branch is up-to-date with remote

Comment: `git merge` does not mean "make all my files exactly the same". Merge is about combining your work with someone else's work. If merge made your files the same as theirs, that would throw away your work. That said, the message `already up to date` means that you have already done this merge! You'll need to show us more about your repository for us to diagnose the problem further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your local `master` branch is not up to date, in which case you should fetch first:

```
# on dev
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

The above two lines are a useful trick in Git to have.  The `git fetch` updates all the local tracking branches, including `origin/master`.  Then, we merge this local tracking branch.  This avoids needing to change branches away from `dev`.

Comment: Hi, that is not the problem, i alwas do a `git pull` from `master` before merging to another branch.

Comment: Well my answer is the only explanation I can conjure to explain the error message.  Maybe check that you in fact pulled by trying out my answer.